# Narrowing int to bool in SFINAE, different output between gcc and clang

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang, sfinae

Consider the following example:

```
template<int i>
struct nice_type;

template<class T>
struct is_nice : std::false_type {};

template<int i>
struct is_nice< nice_type<i> > : std::integral_constant<int, i> {};

template<class T, class = void>
struct pick
{
    typedef std::integral_constant<int, -1> type;
};

template<class T>
struct pick<T, typename std::enable_if< is_nice<T>::value >::type >
{
    typedef std::integral_constant<int, is_nice<T>::value > type;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << pick<int>::type::value << ", ";
    std::cout << pick< nice_type<42> >::type::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Clang (3.4.1) outputs "-1, -1", while GCC(4.9.0) outputs "-1, 42".

The problem lays in the specialization of `pick`. While Gcc seems happy to convert `is_nice<T>::value` (42) to `bool(true)`, clang does not do so, and discards the specialization. Both examples compiled with `-std=c++11`.

Which compiler is right?

Comment: Did you mean `nice_type` instead of `cool_type` in line 8?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is gcc bug [57891](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57891). Conversion of the integral constant `42` to `bool` involves a narrowing conversion, which is not allowed in non-type template arguments. Hence the `enable_if` is ill-formed, and the `pick` specialization should be discarded, as clang correctly does.

*§14.3.2/5 [temp.arg.nontype]*

> The following conversions are performed on each expression used as a
>   non-type *template-argument*. If a non-type *template-argument* cannot be
>   converted to the type of the corresponding *template-parameter* then the
>   program is ill-formed.
>  
>   — For a non-type *template-parameter* of
>   integral or enumeration type, **conversions permitted in a converted
>   constant expression** (5.19) are applied.
>   `...`

*§5.19/3 [expr.const]*

> `...` A **converted constant expression** of type `T` is an expression, implicitly converted to a prvalue of type `T`, where the converted expression is a core
>   constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only user-defined conversions, lvalue-to-rvalue conversions (4.1), integral promotions (4.5), and **integral conversions** (4.7) **other than narrowing conversions** (8.5.4).

*§8.5.4/7 [dcl.init.list]*

> A *narrowing conversion* is an implicit conversion
>   `...`
>   — from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type.

---

This [minimal example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a3bd2cd7fc52ef7) demonstrates the gcc bug:

```
template<bool>
struct foo{};
foo<10> f;

int main() {}
```

gcc-4.9 accepts the code while clang-3.4 rejects it with the following error:

> error: non-type template argument evaluates to 10, which cannot be narrowed to type 'bool' [-Wc++11-narrowing]
>
> ```
>  foo<10> f;
>      ^
> ```

---

The fix to your particular problem is easy. Make sure the non-type template argument to `enable_if` evaluates to a `bool`

```
template<class T>
struct pick<T, typename std::enable_if< is_nice<T>::value != 0 >::type >
//                                                       ^^^^^^
{
    typedef std::integral_constant<int, is_nice<T>::value > type;
};
```