# SFINAE code to detect whether operator<< is implemented for a type behaves differently on Clang and gcc

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I'm just playing around with some SFINAE code and I can't get it to work. I'm using Xcode 12.2 with -std=c++17.
godbolt reveals that Clang does indeed choose the false_type variant no matter what, whereas gcc uses the true_type variant if both template parameters are identical and the operator is implemented, as I would expect it to. See the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct MyStruct {};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyStruct&) {
    return os;
}

template<typename T, typename U = void>
struct has_ostream_operator : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_ostream_operator<T, typename std::enable_if_t<sizeof(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>()), T>> : std::true_type {};

int main() {

    constexpr bool res = has_ostream_operator<MyStruct, MyStruct>::value;
    if constexpr(res) {
        std::cout << "Yes";
    } else {
        std::cout << "No";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain to me what's going on here and why Clang and gcc would behave differently? I've already solved the problem using a different technique, so this is merely for educational purposes :-)

Comment: Ah, found [a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24345399/4386278). Can delete my answer and dupe-close if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you replace the whole `sizeof` construct with `42`, both compilers give you an error about how `sizeof` isn't a `bool` and cannot be narrowed to one.

If you replace it with `1`, there is no error (as 1 can obviously be narrowed to `true`).

With this in mind, let's pass a `bool` explicitly:

```
template<typename T>
struct has_ostream_operator<
    T,
    typename std::enable_if_t<
        sizeof(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>()) != 0,
//                                                                ^^^^^
        T
    >
> : std::true_type {};
```

Now it works.

Both implementations give me `272` for `sizeof(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<MyStruct>())`, so it's just they're handling this error differently during SFINAEness. I think it's [GCC bug 57891](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57891).

Comment: OP says they've solved the problem. They're asking why their code is treated differently by gcc and clang.

Comment: @cigien They switched to a completely different approach. This answer is about what was wrong with _this_ approach, and by my understanding that is what they want to know.